# MVVM и EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Допустим у меня есть много `UserControl`, у каждого из них своя VM, каждая из которой хочет работать с базой. Внутри каждой VM создавать подключение к базе мне кажется неправильным подходом. Как в данном случае выстроить хорошую архитектуру?

Comment: В идеале, должен быть пул подключений наверно, чтобы подключения создавались только при отсутствии свободных. А ещё можно создать подключение на запуске клиента и им пользоваться везде, хотя это и не очень правильно.

Comment: Подключение к базе вообще модельная штука.

Comment: @VladD, допустим пользователь вводит какие то данные, мы их считали и хотим добавить в базу. Как в данном случае действовать? У всех UserControl'ов один и тот же принцип работы, просто они все работают с разными таблицами.

Comment: Ну, VM делает вызов в модель, а как модель сохраняет данные — это её внутреннее дело.

Comment: @VladD, тогда внутри VM будет объект модели, а так как модель для всех общая. то не лучше б ее было вынести как-то за пределы VM?

Comment: @Lightness: Ну, ссылка на объект модели. Может быть общая для всех VM, может быть у каждой VM своя, может быть, она вообще не в VM, а будет лежать в доступном месте. Тут уж как вам угодно.

Comment: @Monk пул подключений реализуется на уровне ADO.NET из коробки